# How do I output a JavaScript array index value as text value in to an html a-tag?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want 26 pages, each containing a letter of the alphabet, but I'm not sure how to pass the index value in as an HTML text value. I have 26 separate pages in my folder titled x-page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>The Alphabet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> This is the main page. </h1>
    <div> These are the letters in the alphabet. </div>

    <a href="a-page.html">[i]</a>
    <a href="b-page.html">[i]</a>
    <a href="c-page.html">[i]</a>
    <a href="d-page.html">[i]</a> <br>
    <a href="e-page.html">[i]</a>
    <a href="f-page.html">[i]</a>
    <a href="g-page.html">[i]</a>
</body>

<script>
    let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']
    for(i=0; i<16; i++){
        console.log(alphabet[i]);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `createElement` and then `appendChild` in the `for` loop.

```js
let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e']; // etc

for(i=0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', alphabet[i] + '-page.html');
  link.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
  document.body.appendChild(link);  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1> This is the main page.</h1>
    <div> These are the letters in the alphabet. </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to do this - you can loop through your alphabets and use i + 1 to display the numbers as array indexing starts from 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>The Alphabet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> This is the main page. </h1>
    <div> These are the letters in the alphabet. </div>
    
    <div id="links"></div>
</body>

<script>
    let alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q'];
    let links = '';
    for(i=0; i < alphabets.length; i++){
        links += ` <a href="${alphabets[i]}-page.html">${i + 1}</a>`
    }
    
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = links;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this,

#### 1: Using [Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']

const target = document.getElementById('target')

alphabet.forEach((v, i) => {
  target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<a href="${v}-page.html">${i}</a><br>`)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>The Alphabet</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> This is the main page. </h1>
  <div> These are the letters in the alphabet. </div>

  <div id="target"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### 2: Using [Element.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']

const target = document.getElementById('target')

alphabet.forEach((v, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement('a')
  el.href = v + '-page.html'
  el.innerText = i + 1;
  target.appendChild(el)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>The Alphabet</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> This is the main page. </h1>
  <div> These are the letters in the alphabet. </div>

  <div id="target"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @jkuehlin consider marking as answer & upvote if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Create `element` and then append it to the parent using `appendChild`

```js
alphab=document.getElementById("alphab")

    let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']
    for(i=0; i<16; i++){
    a=document.createElement("a")
     char=alphabet[i]
    a.href=`${char}+"-page.html"`
    a.innerHTML=`${i} `
    alphab.appendChild(a)
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>The Alphabet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> This is the main page. </h1>
    <div id="alphab">
    </div>    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run the array through a forEach loop. On each loop of the array create an element for an a tag, set its display to block, create a textNode using the value for each value, define the links http and set its attribute for href to the link you define. Lastly append the element to your display content node.

```js
let abet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'];
let div = document.getElementById('cont');

abet.forEach(function(value){
   let aTag = document.createElement('a');
   aTag.style.display = 'block';
   let aTagText = document.createTextNode(value);
   let link = 'http://somesite.org/' + value;
   aTag.setAttribute('href', link);
   aTag.appendChild(aTagText);
   div.append(aTag);   
})
```

```html
<h1> This is the main page. </h1>
    <div> These are the letters in the alphabet. </div>

    <div id="cont">
    </div>
```